# Gridding or interpolating elevation data?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, interpolation, elevation

I wonder if someone can recommend a method for gridding elevation data in QGIS, GRASS or similar?

The elevation data I have is collected along 1m spaced lines at approximately 1 reading per second. So far I've tried inverse distance weighted, bicubic spline, and triangulation methods for the elevation data but all these produce a striping effect in the direction which the data is collected. I am not entirely sure that the error is due to the methods of gridding/interpolation I have been using. However, in tandem with the elevation data I am collecting a series of magnetic measurements (higher density), and these show no linear striping.

Comment: what is the precision of your GPS ?

Comment: Is your target grid with 1 m cells? Perhaps using initial cell size of 0.5 m or 0.7 m or something could reduce stripes. You can resample it later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the accuracy of my GPS (according to the Manufacturer) is 20mm horizontal and 40mm vertical. Its a VRS system.

Comment: For an overview, see http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: many thanks for your suggestions. i'll take a look at the grasswiki on interpolation

Comment: I used this guide: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM